# Minimizing inconclusive range for binary classification with two thresholds

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scikit-learn, compiler-optimization, scipy-optimize

### Problem definition

I have an optimisation problem related to a binary classification tasks.

I have arrays of probabilistic model outputs, `x`, and true binary labels, `y`.

I want to optimize the trade-off between the true positive rate (TPR), true negative rate (TNR), and the number of inconclusive predictions.

More precisely, I want to minimise the number of inconclusive predictions (`|S|`, where `S` is the set of excluded indexes), constrained on TPR and TNR exceeding some given constants `p` and `q`, over the threshold variables `a` and `b`, where `0 < a < b < 1`. Model predictions between `a` and `b` are considered inconclusive, and hence excluded.

The optimization problem can formally be defined as:

[image: optimization_priblem]

### Attempt

```py
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


def objective_function(
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    a, b = thresholds
    included_indices = (probs < a) | (probs >= b)
    # exclusion rate
    r = 1 - float(np.mean(included_indices))
    return r


def calculate_rates(
    targets: np.ndarray,
    probs: np.ndarray,
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    a, b = thresholds
    idx = (probs < a) | (probs >= b)
    y_true_non_excluded = targets[idx]
    y_pred_non_excluded = (probs[idx] >= b).astype(int)
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(
        y_true_non_excluded,
        y_pred_non_excluded,
    ).ravel()
    tpr = tp / (tp + fn) if (tp + fn) > 0 else 0
    tnr = tn / (tn + fp) if (tn + fp) > 0 else 0
    return tpr, tnr


def constraint_tnr(
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
    p: float,
) -> float:
    tnr = calculate_rates(targets, probs, thresholds)[1]
    return tnr - p


def constraint_tpr(
    thresholds: Tuple[float, float],
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
    q: float,
) -> float:
    tpr = calculate_rates(targets, probs, thresholds)[0]
    return tpr - q


def optimize_thresholds(
    probs: np.ndarray,
    targets: np.ndarray,
    p: float,
    q: float,
    initial_guess: Tuple[float, float],
) -> Tuple[float, float]:

    # Constrained minimization
    constraints = (
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_tnr, 'args': (probs, targets, p)},  # TNR > p (1)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_tpr, 'args': (probs, targets, q)},  # TPR > q (2)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda thrs: thrs[0]},                         # 0 < a   (3)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda thrs: 1 - thrs[1]},                     # b < 1   (4)
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda thrs: thrs[1] - thrs[0]},               # a < b   (5)
        # (3) and (5) => b > 0
        # (4} and (5) => a < 1
    )

    # Bounds for a and b (0 < a ≤ b < 1)
    # bounds = [(0, 1), (0, 1)]
    # Method COBYLA cannot handle bounds. Therefore, we use constraints instead.    
 
    # Run the optimization
    result = minimize(
        objective_function,
        x0=initial_guess,
        args=(probs, targets),
        method='COBYLA',
        # bounds=bounds,
        constraints=constraints,
    )

    # Check if the optimization was successful and display the results
    if result.success:
        optimal_a, optimal_b = result.x
        # exclusion rate
        optimal_r = objective_function((optimal_a, optimal_b), probs, targets)

        # Calculate TNR and TPR for the non-excluded cases
        non_excluded_indices = (probs < optimal_a) | (probs >= optimal_b)
        y_true_non_excluded = targets[non_excluded_indices]
        y_pred_non_excluded = (probs[non_excluded_indices] >= optimal_b).astype(int)
        optimal_tnr, optimal_tpr = calculate_rates(
            y_true_non_excluded, y_pred_non_excluded, (optimal_a, optimal_b)
        )

        print(f'Optimal a: {optimal_a}, Optimal b: {optimal_b}')
        print(f'Exclusion rate r: {optimal_r}')
        print(f'True Negative Rate: {optimal_tnr}')
        print(f'True Positive Rate: {optimal_tpr}')
    else:
        print(result)
        raise ValueError('Optimisation was not successful.')

    return optimal_a, optimal_b

def main() -> None:
    df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
    x = df['x'].to_numpy()
    y = df['y'].to_numpy()

    # works
    optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=(0.2, 0.8))

    # does not work
    optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=(0.3, 0.7))

    # optimal solution
    optimal_thresholds = (0.3610841998732966, 0.6057616712011725)
    # does not work
    optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=optimal_thresholds)
```

### Issue

With an initial guess of `a = 0.2` and `b = 0.8`, i.e.

```py
# setup x, y
...
optimize_thresholds(x, y, p=0.9, q=0.9, initial_guess=(0.2, 0.8))
```

it converges to a seemingly optimal solution:

```
Optimal a: 0.370554470806464, Optimal b: 0.5917056391027792
Exclusion rate r: 0.13576158940397354
True Negative Rate: 0.9005128205128206
True Positive Rate: 0.9002911208151383
(0.370554470806464, 0.5917056391027792)
```

However, when `a` and `b` are initialised to most other values, even values close to the optimal solution, e.g. `a = 0.37` and `b = 0.6`, it fails to find a solution.

```
 message: Did not converge to a solution satisfying the constraints. See `maxcv` for magnitude of violation.
 success: False
  status: 4
     fun: 0.13355408388520973
       x: [ 3.719e-01  5.891e-01]
    nfev: 18
   maxcv: 0.000944081336238245

ValueError: Optimisation was not successful.
```

I would like to improve the stability of the my solution, to not depend on a seemingly arbitrary choice of initialisation.

### Alternative methods

With **SLSQP**, the optimisation fails if the initialisation does not satisfy the constraint related to TNR, and TPR, and returns the initialisation values otherwise, i.e. a sub-optimal solution with TNR and TPR unnecessarily high, leading to a larger number of excluded cases than the optimal solution.

#### Bound-Constrained minimisation

Both **COBYLA** and **SLSQP** are methods for constrained minimisation. An initial thought was to translate the constraints into bounds and use a bound-constrained minimisation method, e.g. Powell, Nelder-Mead, or L-BFGS-B. However, the TPR and TNR constraints are more complex, as they depend on the values of `a` and `b`. As far as I know, these cannot be directly translated into bounds for `a` and `b` because they are not simple linear constraints.

### Sample data

[sample_data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bd6j6zcetxt5ymfazskh8/sample_data.csv?rlkey=nwguy7dvxi4e1j6vafl2m0lg3&dl=0)

### Similar problem

I have found a paper that addresses a similar problem; however, instead of constraints on the TPR and the TNR independently, they have a constraint on the overall accuracy.

Patrone PN, Bedekar P, Pisanic N, et al. Optimal decision theory for diagnostic testing: Minimizing indeterminate classes with applications to saliva-based SARS-CoV-2 antibody assays. *Mathematical Biosciences*. 2022 Sep 1;351:108858. doi: [10.1016/j.mbs.2022.108858](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mbs.2022.108858).